# Why do writes to MySQL fail to persist when run from Python's unittest?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, amazon-rds, python-unittest, mysql-connector-python

I am currently writing a test case for a newly-created MySQL database using unittest in Python 3.8. The database is an AWS RDS instance running Aurora MySQL 5.6 — it has a table `users` with a single primary key field `uuid VARCHAR(36)`. The test case is as follows:

```
import unittest
import mysql.connector
from config import MYSQL_CONNECTION_INFO

class SQLSchemaTests(unittest.TestCase):
    """Verifies the correct behavior of the schema itself. (i.e. that the tables were set up correctly)"""
    
    def setUp(self):
        self.cnxn = mysql.connector.connect(**MYSQL_CONNECTION_INFO)
        self.cursor = self.cnxn.cursor()
        
    def tearDown(self):
        self.cnxn.close()
    
    def test_create_users(self):
        """Verify that a client can create user entries in the data store with appropriate parameters."""
        self.cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) from users")
        user_entries_count = self.cursor.fetchone()[0]
        self.assertEqual(user_entries_count, 0)
        
        self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO users (uuid) VALUES ('aaa-bbb-ccc-ddd-eee')")
        
        self.cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) from users")
        user_entries_count = self.cursor.fetchone()[0]
        self.assertEqual(user_entries_count, 1)
```

What confuses me is that this test case passes every time it's run — in other words with no cleanup action on my part it doesn't fail due to duplicate entries. I used PyCharm's debugger to place a breakpoint after the `INSERT` statement, and then ran the `SELECT COUNT(*) from users` in a separate database console while test execution was paused: the result came back as zero. What is more, when I used the database console to write an identical entry to the `users` table *only then* did the test fail due to a duplicate entry.

I'd like to know the following:

- Why don't the `INSERT` statements within the unit test persist to the table? Is it caused by the MySQL connector, unittest, or something else?
- What are the rules that dictates how this happens? Under what circumstances is this behavior guaranteed?
- Is there any official documentation that could clarify these points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to see the insertion persist between tests I needed to add `self.cnxn.commit()` after I called `execute` on the `INSERT` statement: the [Python connector docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlconnection-commit.html) specify that auto-commit is disabled by default.

Moreover, the reason that I could get back an updated count from *within* the test but not from the separate database console is due to **transaction isolation** at the database level (in this case, set to `REPEATABLE-READ`). More information is available in the [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html) and in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)) on isolation in databases.